cortex-m4 core clocking on st32f4 example using cmsis library
I ask for a review of the code for basic clocking of the stm32f401ccu core, for simple blinking of the LED.
void ClockInit(void){
    //RCC->CR = 0x0000XX81;
    RCC->CR |= (1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
    RCC->CR |= (1 << RCC_CR_HSEON_Pos);
    __IO int StrtUpcntr;
    for (StrtUpcntr = 0 ;    ;   StrtUpcntr++)
    {
        if(RCC->CR & (1 << RCC_CR_HSIRDY_Pos))break;
        if(StrtUpcntr > 0x1000){
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (StrtUpcntr = 0 ;    ;   StrtUpcntr++)
    {
        if(RCC->CR & (1 << RCC_CR_HSERDY_Pos)){
            RCC->CR |= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
            break;
            }
        if(StrtUpcntr > 0x1000){
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSEON_Pos);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x24003010;              //see EASYPLL
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_Pos); 
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x192 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x08 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x03 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos);
    FLASH->ACR = 0x00000000;
    FLASH->ACR |= (0x02 << FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Pos);
    RCC->CR |= (1 << RCC_CR_PLLON_Pos);
    for(StrtUpcntr = 0; ;   StrtUpcntr++){
        if (1 & (1 << RCC_CR_PLLRDY_Pos)){
            break;
        }
        if(StrtUpcntr > 0x1000){
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_PLLON_Pos);
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    RCC->CFGR = 0x00000000;
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 << RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Pos);
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 << RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Pos);
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x02 << RCC_CFGR_SW_Pos);
    for(StrtUpcntr = 0; ; StrtUpcntr++){
        if(0x02 & (0x02 << RCC_CFGR_SWS_Pos)){
            break;
        }
        if (StrtUpcntr > 0x1000){
            RCC->CFGR &= ~(0x02 << RCC_CFGR_SW_Pos);
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_PLLON_Pos);
            RCC->CR &= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos);
            return 1;
        }
    }


}

first attempt at timing, line 58 didn't work:
https://github.com/KosorukiyShiva/VSCODE_F401/tree/main
current version where changes were made to the ClockInit function and pc13 functions were removed:
https://github.com/KosorukiyShiva/VSCODE_F401/tree/test

Rather than (1 << RCC_CR_HSIRDY_Pos) just use RCC_CR_HSIRDY.

Your loop counter isn't a hardware IO register, so get rid of __IO.

You can't return 1 from a function with type void.

RCC->CR |= ~(1 << RCC_CR_HSION_Pos); is a very unusual thing to do. Are you sure this line is correct? Ditto RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 << RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Pos); and similar.
